# XHR For Loop - Unexpected End of Input Error

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am attempting to make multiple XHR requests to download a total of 3 JSON feeds. Unfortunately I am only able to get one transferComplete() to execute before I get hit with a unexpected end of input error. I have checked my syntax and as far as I can tell it looks good. Why is this happening?

```
function getJSON(){
    feedObject["url"]["0"] = "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_day.geojson",
    feedObject["url"]["1"] = "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_week.geojson",
    feedObject["url"]["2"] = "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_month.geojson";

    var xhr = [];

    for (a = 0; a < 3; a++) {

        (function(a){
            xhr[a] = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr[a].addEventListener("load", transferComplete(a));
            xhr[a].open("GET", feedObject["url"][a], true);
            xhr[a].send(null);

            feedObject["quakesMag"][a] = [],
            feedObject["quakesPlace"][a] = [],
            feedObject["quakesTime"][a] = [];
        })(a);

    }

    function transferComplete(a) {
        // receiving data
        loadText.innerText = "Getting USGS Data "+(a+1)+ "/3";
        var response = JSON.parse(xhr[a].responseText);
        feedObject["quakesTitle"][a] = response["metadata"]["title"];

        for (var i = 0, len = response["features"].length; i < len; i++) {
            if (response["features"][i]["properties"]["mag"] != null) {
                quakes = [],
                quakeCount = 0;
                quakes.push(response["features"][i]);
            }
        }

        for (var x = quakes.length - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
            var quake = quakes[x],
                quakeCoord = quake["geometry"]["coordinates"],
                quakeMag = quake["properties"]["mag"],
                quakePlace = quake["properties"]["place"],
                quakeTime = quake["properties"]["time"];

            quakeCount++;

            feedObject["quakesMag"][a].push(quakeMag);
            feedObject["quakesPlace"][a].push(quakePlace);
            feedObject["quakesTime"][a].push(quakeTime);

        }

        feedObject["quakesCount"][a] = quakeCount;

        if (a == 2){ renderData(); }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The load event listener using multiple AJAX requests was causing the error.

Using on ready state changed solved the issue.

```
(function(a){
            xhr[a] = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr[a].open("GET", feedObject["url"][a], true);

            xhr[a].onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) {
                if (xhr[a].readyState == 4) {
                    if(xhr[a].status == 200)
                        transferComplete(a);
                    else
                        alert("Error loading page\n");
                }
            };
            xhr[a].send(null);

            feedObject["quakesCoord"][a] = [],
            feedObject["quakesMag"][a] = [],
            feedObject["quakesPlace"][a] = [],
            feedObject["quakesTime"][a] = [];
        })(a);
```